# Querying Bigtable row keys by suffix?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I would like to perform some housekeeping on a Bigtable table with a Python script. My row key uses date as a suffix. Is there any way to query Bigtable based on the row key suffix?

Comment: You can look at google-cloud samples. There is code for searching by prefix. Might help with changing it to suffix. (use endswith() function for it)
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples/bigtable-reads-prefix#bigtable_reads_prefix-python

Answer (score 1):

Bigtable is not optimized to search by suffix – it is a sorted key-value map, so you would need to scan the entire table to do this. You typically want to [design a schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design) where your queries are focused on the prefix of the row key.

Now, it is possible to do and shouldn't have huge performance implications if you only need to do this type of query every now and then, but shouldn't be used for any production serving.

You can do a read with a [row key regex filter](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#row-key-regex) and just specify a suffix. In Python, it might look like this:

```
def filter_limit_row_regex(project_id, instance_id, table_id):
    client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
    instance = client.instance(instance_id)
    table = instance.table(table_id)

    rows = table.read_rows(
        filter_=row_filters.RowKeyRegexFilter(".*#20190501$".encode("utf-8"))
    )
    for row in rows:
        print_row(row)
```

If you can, it would be best to combine this with a row key prefix to at least limit the scope of the query, but I understand if that isn't possible with what you're trying to do.